# How to pass parameters with control event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, telerik, dynamic-programming

Need to pass parameter with this event handler, is it possible to send parameter with event handler? Please check my `RadTreeView2_NodeExpand` syntax.

```
internal void LoadTree(RadTreeView treeView, System.Collections.IEnumerable r)
{
   LoadRootNodes(ref treeView, TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSideCallBack, r);
   treeView += RadTreeView2_NodeExpand(r);
}

public void RadTreeView2_NodeExpand(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e, System.Collections.IEnumerable r)
{                        
   if (e.Node.Nodes.Count == 0)
      PopulateNodeOnDemand(e, TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSide, r);
}

private static void PopulateNodeOnDemand(RadTreeNodeEventArgs e, TreeNodeExpandMode expandMode, System.Collections.IEnumerable r)
{
   //List<testTable> data = GetChildNodes(e.Node.Value);

   foreach (testTable row in r)
   {
      RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode();
      node.Text = row.Address;//row["Title"].ToString();
      node.Value = row.ID; //row["CategoryId"].ToString();
      //if (Convert.ToInt32(row["ChildrenCount"]) > 0)
      //{
      //    node.ExpandMode = expandMode;
      //}
      e.Node.Nodes.Add(node);
   }

   e.Node.Expanded = true;
}       

private static void LoadRootNodes(ref RadTreeView treeView, TreeNodeExpandMode expandMode, System.Collections.IEnumerable data)
{
    //DataTable data = GetData(new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductCategories WHERE ParentId IS NULL"));

    foreach (testTable row in data)
    {
       RadTreeNode node = new RadTreeNode();
       node.Text = row.Address;//row["Title"].ToString();
       node.Value = row.ID;//row["CategoryId"].ToString();
       node.ExpandMode = expandMode;
       treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
 }
```

If have any question, please ask, any type of suggestion will be accepted thanks in advance

Comment: what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot add a parameter to an existing event. And if you could, how would you pass a value in?

You already store `row.ID` in the Value property, that is the correct way to retrieve information for a specific TreeNode. So find a way to store your data elsewhere and make it accessible on RowId.

Comment: Henk Holterman,thanks for reply.Please check my syntax ,it's a web application ,so i can not store my value in control tag,i dont like to store my value in session so parameter base delegate control event can do this easily.

Comment: _i dont like to store my value in session_ sounds like a weak argument. Would you rather pump it all to the client as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this. But be aware that your Enumerable will be bound on event binding.

```
internal void LoadTree(RadTreeView treeView, System.Collections.IEnumerable r)
    {
        var enumerable = r as object[] ?? r.Cast<object>().ToArray();
        LoadRootNodes(ref treeView, TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSideCallBack, enumerable);
        treeView.NodeExpand += (s, e) =>
            {
             if (e.Node.Nodes.Count == 0)
               PopulateNodeOnDemand(e, 
                                    TreeNodeExpandMode.ServerSide,
                                    enumerable)
            };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void setup(string someData)
{
     Object.assignHandler((sender) => evHandler(sender,someData));
}
public void evHandler(Object sender, string someData)
{
    // need someData here!!!
}
```